# Решение задачи с вводом числа и буквы (использовать cin>> & cout<<)

Tags: c++, cin

Нуждаюсь в помощи знатоков языка С++. Приходиться мне учить вместе с сыном С++, так как изучение данного языка они проходят в колледже, а он его не может понять.

**Задали вот такую задачку:**

*Напишите алгоритм, который считывает целые числа из стандартного ввода до тех пор, пока пользователь не введет символ «f» или «F», чтобы завершить ввод, и напечатает максимальное значение, найденное между ними (вам понадобится альтернативная структура и повторяющаяся структура).*

Использовать нужно в задаче, я так понял cin + cout.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Что именно не понятно в задании? Если бы требовалось ввести 10 чисел и найти максимум среди них, то вы сами бы написали такую программу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю вам вариант решения. Если правильно понял найти надо разницу между минимальным и максимальным значением? (1 -100 20 4) 20 - (-100) = 120. Если нет то посмотрите **второй вариант** как я понял задачу - просто максимальное значение. (1, -10, 20) - 20 максимальное значение. Важные моменты описал описал для понимания что происходит. Стартовые значения выбрал как **INT_MIN**, потому что **-100000** условное - тоже целое число, поэтому взял для надежности взял минимально возможное число, которое помещается в тип данных **int** ( 4 байта ). **int** как тип взял потому что обычно он подразумается если не сказанно другого. У вас таких данных в задаче нет.

```cpp
#include <iostream> // std::cout / std::cin
#include <climits> // INT_MIN
#include <string> // std::string

int main()
{
    int minValue = INT_MIN, maxValue = INT_MIN // -2^31 степени
    
    std::string user_input;
    const char* PossibleChars = "-0123456789";
    
    // бесконечный ввод
    while(std::cin >> user_input) {
        size_t notaDigit = user_input.find_first_not_of(PossibleChars);
        // если нашли не разшенный символ (не число и знак минус тоже нужен для отрицательных чисел) получается какой-то символ
        // std::string - массив символов, а нас интересует один, поэтому берем нулевой элемент (в C++ индексация массивов начинается с нуля)
        if(notaDigit != std::string::npos) {
            if(user_input[0] == 'f' || user_input[0] == 'F')
                // прерываем цикл и обрабатываем вводимые значения переходим к месту где *@*
                break;
        }
        else {
            int currentValue = std::stoi(user_input);
            // для первого ввода, что бы было откуда отталкиваться
            if(minValue == INT_MIN && maxValue == INT_MIN)
                minValue = maxValue = currentValue;
            if(currentValue < minValue)
                minValue = currentValue;
            else if(currentValue > maxValue)
                maxValue = currentValue;
        }
    }
    
    // Важный момент! int хранит целые числа от -2^31 до 2^31-1. меньеше или больше данные тип хранит не может

    // *@*
    std::cout << "Результат = " << maxValue - minValue << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

2-ой вариант понимания задачи.

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout / std::cin
#include <climits> // INT_MIN
#include <string> // std::string

int main()
{
    
    int maxValue = INT_MIN; // -2^31 степени
    
    std::string user_input;
    const char* PossibleChars = "-0123456789";
    
    // бесконечный ввод
    while(std::cin >> user_input) {
        size_t notaDigit = user_input.find_first_not_of(PossibleChars);
        // если нашли не разшенный символ (не число) и знак минус тоже нужен получается какой-то символ
        // std::string - массив символов, а нас интересует один, поэтому берем нулевой элемент (в C++ индексация массивов начинается с нуля)
        if(notaDigit != std::string::npos) {
            if(user_input[0] == 'f' || user_input[0] == 'F')
                // прерываем цикл и обрабатываем вводимые значения переходим к месту где *@*
                break;
        }
        else {
            int currentValue = std::stoi(user_input);
            
            if(maxValue == INT_MIN)
                maxValue = currentValue;
            else if(currentValue > maxValue)
                maxValue = currentValue;
        }
    }
    
    // Важный момент! int хранит целые числа от -2^31 до 2^31 - 1. меньеше или больше данные тип хранит не может

    // *@*
    std::cout << "Максимальное значение = " << maxValue << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да, спасибо INT_MIN конечно :)

Comment: 32-битный `int` хранит целые в диапазоне от `- 2^31` до `2^31 - 1`.

Comment: @wololo спасибо, так и было у меня изначально )

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант, производится ввод сразу чисел, далее используются некоторые [свойства потока](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/iostate/) ввода (`istream` (cin)) для анализа на ввод символа 'f' или 'F'.

Если при вводе чисел найдена нефатальная ошибка (например, вместо 'f' или 'F' ввести 'G'), то программа предлагает повторить ввод с начала.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

  bool done = false;
  int max = 0;
  
  do {
    cout << "Input numbers, stop with 'f' of 'F'\n";
    int n = 0, x;
    char c;

    while (cin >> x) {
      ++n;
      if (n == 1)
        max = x;
      else if (x > max)
        max = x;
    }
    
    if (cin.eof()) {
      cout << "\nBye!\n";
      break;
    }
    cin.clear();
    
    if (cin >> c) {
      if (c == 'f' || c == 'F') {
        cout << "max = " << max << '\n';
        done = true;
      }
    }
    if (!done) {
      cout << "Skip to \\n...\n";
      while (cin.read(&c, 1) && c != '\n');
      if (cin.fail()) {
        cout << "Can't read more...\n";
        break;
      }
    }
  } while (!done);

  
  cout << "End\n";
  
  return !done;
}
```